# Dataframe.groupby function not working correctly on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have initialized a df like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('pokemon_data.csv')
df
```

[image: pokemon_dataset]

Running df.info() for this dataset:

```
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 800 entries, 0 to 799
Data columns (total 12 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------      --------------  ----- 
 0   #           800 non-null    int64 
 1   Name        800 non-null    object
 2   Type 1      800 non-null    object
 3   Type 2      414 non-null    object
 4   HP          800 non-null    int64 
 5   Attack      800 non-null    int64 
 6   Defense     800 non-null    int64 
 7   Sp. Atk     800 non-null    int64 
 8   Sp. Def     800 non-null    int64 
 9   Speed       800 non-null    int64 
 10  Generation  800 non-null    int64 
 11  Legendary   800 non-null    bool  
dtypes: bool(1), int64(8), object(3)
memory usage: 69.7+ KB
```

Next I am using the groupby function to calculate the mean, using this code:

```
a = df.groupby(['Type 1']).mean()
display(a)
```

That is displaying an error:

[image: Error]

I was expecting to see something like this:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: We need to see the datatypes of your dataframe and even better some sample data in text format that makes it possible to easily recreate your error (versus typing out what we see in images). As a rule, always run `df.info()` after loading data from csv (at least, especially when you are starting out). Also, please no pictures or images in your questions or your questions will almost certainly be downvoted! [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: per [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.mean.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.mean), starting from Pandas 2.0.0, you might want to pass `numeric_only=True` to `mean`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing it to this should do it for you.

```py
a = df.groupby('Type 1')
a.mean()
```

You can try mentioning the column name for which you want the mean to be calculated.

```py
a.Attack.mean()
```